# Pass array from Controller to Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony, symfony4

I have a Symfony project where I make an AJAX call.

**Controller.php**

```php
/**
     * @Route("/juegoAuto", options={"expose"=true}, name="juegoAuto")
     */
    public function juegoAuto(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            (...)

            $idPartida = $jugador->getPartida();
            $jugadores = $em->getRepository(Jugador::class)->findBy(['partida' => $idPartida]);

            return new JsonResponse(['id' => $id, 'jugadores' => $jugadores]);
        } else {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Y te pillé');
        }
    }
```

The parameter 'id' shows me well, the problem is with the array of 'jugadores' that I receive in the .js file and by console it prints this to me:

`functions.js:212 Object`

`functions.js:213 clicod: [object Object] - Indice: 0`

`functions.js:212 Object`

`functions.js:213 clicod: [object Object] - Indice: 1`

I have tried it in many ways:

```
$.each(data['jugadores'], function(indice, valor) {
    console.dir(valor);
    console.log('clicod: ' + valor + ' - Indice: ' + indice);
})
```

`console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data['jugadores'])))`

`console.log(data['jugadores'].toString())`

And there is no way. If anyone could help me ... thanks. The problem is that it says that they are Objects but I enter them and they are empty. On the other hand, if I make the same request and print it in twig, it does return data.

[image: image of what the console returns]

Comment: What do you get if you dd($jugadores); before your response ?

Comment: `console.log(data['jugadores'])` return `(2) [{...}, {...}]` but when I look the content, I get the image above

Comment: the problem is, that json_encode (which is used by default if you provide entities to jsonresponse) doesn't encode private properties, and your properties are probably all private. either you can do a symfony serializer or you can implement [JsonSerializable](https://php.net/JsonSerializable) on your entity. otherwise you will continue to get "empty" entities. I doubt that there are no such questions so far, so scour the internet for your answers ;o) have a look at the JMSSerializerBundle.

Comment: I was actually asking about the dd() output from php, not the console.log output from js.

Comment: i agree to jakumi you need to serialize the data

Comment: @Jakumi is right, you could also get an array result from the repository (instead of entities) by making your own request => ...getQuery()->getArrayResult(); This way your selected data would get encoded.